MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017 error when docker composing
I am getting the following error message when I try to run docker compose up:
arkheia-node-server   | MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
arkheia-node-server   |     at _handleConnectionErrors (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:875:11)
arkheia-node-server   |     at NativeConnection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:826:11) {
arkheia-node-server   |   reason: TopologyDescription {
arkheia-node-server   |     type: 'Unknown',
arkheia-node-server   |     servers: Map(1) { '127.0.0.1:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
arkheia-node-server   |     stale: false,
arkheia-node-server   |     compatible: true,
arkheia-node-server   |     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
arkheia-node-server   |     localThresholdMS: 15,
arkheia-node-server   |     setName: null,
arkheia-node-server   |     maxElectionId: null,
arkheia-node-server   |     maxSetVersion: null,
arkheia-node-server   |     commonWireVersion: 0,
arkheia-node-server   |     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
arkheia-node-server   |   },
arkheia-node-server   |   code: undefined
arkheia-node-server   | }
arkheia-node-server exited with code 0

This is my .env file:
PORT=4000
MONGODB_URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1/ArkheiaData
MONGODB_TEST_URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1/ArkheiaTestDB

this is my docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.7'

services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: arkheia-server
    container_name: arkheia-node-server
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - ./server/:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    env_file: ./server/.env
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    networks:
      - app-network
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - app-network
  client:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: arkheia-client
    container_name: arkheia-react-client
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - server
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
    app-network:
        driver: bridge

volumes:
    data-volume:
    node_modules:
    web-root:
      driver: local

The node version I am using is v18.12.1
I don't actually now what could cause the problem. I tried to manually connect to mongodb compass, and tried changing the .env to
MONGODB_URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ArkheiaData and nothing changed. I am making a MERN application with a frontend and a backend. This problem persisted for a long time now, but I want to be able to just docker compose up everything and run a localhost. This project will be forwarded to other users, so keep in mind this.
UPDATE:
after changing this:
MONGODB_URI=mongodb://mongo/ArkheiaData
MONGODB_TEST_URI=mongodb://mongo/ArkheiaTestDB

I still get this:
arkheia-react-client  | Proxy error: Could not proxy request /simulation_runs from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:4000.
arkheia-react-client  | See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).

but the previous error was fixed.

Your Mongo URI's should be mongodb://mongo/ArkheiaTestDB. You use the service name as the hostname when communicating between containers on the same docker compose network.
